# How to handle registration with phone number or email address in database?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, database, authentication

I'm writing a webapp that needs registration. I want my users be able to register with email address or phone number. Then they can login using phone number, email address or username, just like facebook, twitter, Instagram and etc.

My question is how to handle this in the back end database?
How to handle it during login ? How to understand weather the entered value is phone number or email(in registration)? Do I need three fields for each user in database with unique constraint separately, or  should they be together?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Do I need three fields for each user in database with unique constraint separately?**
Possibly yes. Users can use one out of the three options depending on which one they prefer. Since you don't know which field they will give you, all fields may accept null( ie can be empty). But you have to check that of all the values you are submitting, just one of email or phone-no or username is included.
And I'm sure you'd need other values too apart from  the above three eg password etc.

**2. How to handle it in login query? How to understand that the entered value is phone number or email(in registration)?**
Regular expression will solve that problem (When they are login in).
When they are signing up give them options as explained briefly below. But when they are loging in use regular expression to determine if they are login in with username or with phone-no, or with email and take appropriate action.
You can find regex tutorials for the language in use online by googling it.

EXPLANATION
Since you are talking about web app, I assume html is involved, whatever you are using as markup, there has to be three input fields as options and you can let your users know that only one is sufficient. That is, you don't want them to give their phone no. and email at the same time. Note that if you require username for signup and would want to optionally use username&password pairs for login, then each username must be unique. In this particular case you'd need to query the database as soon as they are done with typing in the username input field to check if the username has been taken. This can be accomplish using Ajax
and you can find ajax tutorials online. If it is taken you let them know and stop them from submitting but if it's not they can continue. 
As stated above, you need to let them know they can only give their username or phone number or email address but not both. You do this by including 'Or' just above the fields.
For you to force them to type only one of the values, you need to capture when they have begun typing in any of the optional fields, so if they have started typing in one field, you disable or hide the other two fields. With this particular solution you don't even need regular expression, you just have to include an attribute that can help you determine what type of value they give you, example:

```html
<form class="form-inputs">
    <div class="unique-options">
        <span> Phone No </span>
        <input class="opts" id="phone-no" type="phone">
        <span> Or email </span>
        <input class="opts" id="email-address" type="email">
        <span> Or username </span>
        <input class="opts" id="username" type="email">
    </div>
    <span> Password </span>
    <input type="password" id="psw-input">
    <button type="submit" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Use javascript to determine what value they are giving you. Here am using jquery**

```js
var valueType,ph,em,usrn,passw;
ph = $("#phone-no");
em = $("#email-address");
usrn = $("#username");
passw = $("#password").val();
$("input.opts").keyup(function(e){
   
   /* If they've begun typing in one input field, hide the rest two */
    
    valuType = $(e.target).attr("id");
    if(valueType == "phone-no"){
        em.prev.hide();
        usrn.prev.hide();
        em.hide();
        usrn.hide();
    } else if(valueType == "email-address"){
         ph.prev.hide();
         usrn.prev.hide();
         ph.hide();
         usrn.hide(); 
    } else if(valueType == "username"){
        em.prev.hide();
        ph.prev.hide();
        em.hide();
        ph.hide();
    }
)};

$("#submit-btn").click(function(e){
    $(e).preventDefault();
    
    /*
    * I assume you have three separate scripts on the server
    * to handle the query
    * for each three inputs you are expecting 
    */
    if(valueType == "phone-no"){
        $.post( 'http://script-that-inserts-into-phone-no-field',
          data: {phone: valueType, password: passw},
          function(data) {
      
          },"text/html"
      );
    } else if(valueType == "email-address"){
        $.post( 'http://script-that-inserts-into-email-field.extension',
          data: {email: valueType, password: passw},
          function(data) {
      
          },"text/html"
      );    
    } else if(valueType == "username"){
        $.post( 'http://script-that-inserts-into-username-field.extension',
          data: {username: valueType, password: passw},
          function(data) {
      
          },"text/html"
      );
    }
});
```

So this way you can use your server side script to check if the value-type is phone-no you insert the value provided by user in phone-no column leaving other two columns(email&username) null (for that row).
You may check that you know how to attach attribute and values in markup element and retrieve the value on server, sometimes it might be elegant to use Javascript to capture the useful fields and submit the relevant values they hold to the server.

*Notice that you said nothing about Server side language in use, so this post is not language specific.*

Instead of trying to determine what type of value they are giving you before submitting to a script and having multiple scripts to handle each cases as above, you may just submit the values to one script.
But this one script need to have three queries stored in three variable and which query variable you use will be determined by the value of received valueType.
 I don't know the sever side language you are using, I could have included that.

This was just to give an idea of what you can think of and if you are using this solution please note that the code was not tested but it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

A change in your SQL query can make this possible. Here’s how to do this.

```
<label>Username / E-Mail</label>
<span style="line-height: 1.5em;"><input type="text" name="login" /></span>
```

your table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` text NOT NULL,
`email` text NOT NULL,
`password` text NOT NULL,
`psalt` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

SQL query will be like this as your login system should authorize if the user entered username or email

```
SELECT id,password,psalt FROM users WHERE (username=:login OR email=:login) AND password=:pass
```

and you know the rest

Comment: thanks for your fast answer, but how about registration? in registration, how can I understand the entered value if it's email or phone? and another question how about uniqueness of email, phone and username? should I check it manually in code and query or I can use the DBMS for this? how? thanks

Comment: `username` , 'phone',`email` are stored separately in a table for registration,
why do you want to know what the user enters (we are storing the values separately ) , 
if at all you want it anyway then you can use jquery to know if its a phone number or email 

uniqueness of email, phone can be checked by server side validation (use onkeyup or onclick to send the value to db check if exists and throw an error )

Comment: let me ask in other way, do I need separate APIs for different kinds of registration? for example, an API for email registration and another for phone registration? another question is about uniqueness of fields and I would be appreciated if you help me for this. thanks a lot.